# Internet Explorer hover/rgba/opacity/css3 compatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, internet-explorer-9, rgba

I am using CSS3 with an rgba alpha opacity hover to display text over an image when the user hovers.

Works fine in chrome, firefox and safari but when trying in internet explorer (9) it just shows the image and hovering does nothing.

Check out the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/b16pow50/

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  height: 396px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #000;
}
div:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%" rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="60%">- 0</td>
        <td width="20%" rowspan="5" align="right">
          <a href="#" target="frame">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/71x50/f00" alt=" " width="71" height="50" border="0">
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>- 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>- 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>- 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>- 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Although you do have two `;` in the first style, which is invalid.

Comment: Editted your question and removed the second `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo works in Internet Explorer 9. The issue may be that you are viewing the page in an older document mode, thus reducing support for things like `:hover` on non-link elements, and `rgba` color.

Press F12 to open up your Developer Tools and check the document mode from there. Alternatively, you can also log the value of `document.documentMode` to your console output as well. You should expect Internet Explorer 9 to be in IE 9's document mode, as opposed to something earlier.

[image]

The ensure that your document loads in Standards Mode to begin with (which in IE 9 is the *9* Document Mode), start your document with the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Nothing should come before this in your document.

From then on, adhere closely to the [HTML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). As an example of one deviation from the spec, you are placing a `table` within a `span`. The [`<span>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) is meant to hold *only phrasing content*, such as `<a>`, `<strong>`, `<em>`, etc.

Comment: It was because of not starting the document without the <!DOCTYPE html>, is there a way for me to create this correctly without using <span>?

Comment: @JamesK Certainly, but I'm not sure what your desired end-result is. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve, and I will gladly help you explore your options.

Comment: To be able to add description to a photo whilst on the hover over. This was the method I could figure out that allowed me to control the layout of what I wanted (I tried for a long time using lists to create bulletpoints but no luck). Here is the finished product: http://jsfiddle.net/w8dvhv8p/

Comment: It sounds like you should look into [`<figure>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) and [`<figcaption>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element) elements. You would place both an `<img>` and a `<figcaption>` *inside* the `<figure>`. You could then hide the caption if you like, and reveal it when the user hovers the `<figure>`. You may need to load the HTML5Shiv in some cases: https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv